# How to fetch the text values from the dd tag using selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, uiautomation

I am automating one Project in my organization and came across one issue. I am very new to automation and selenium.

Issue that i am facing: not able to capture the text inside the dd tag in the html

[image]

The Highlighted text in the UI is what I want to capture and adjacent to it is the html code

Also Attaching the script I am writing 
And the Console Output[image]

[image]

I am able to fetch the value from the dt tag but not from dd tag

Can Somebody help me with this?

Comment: First of all - please post code and not images. There is no way someone can quote the code in their answers if you post images. If you are referring to the `dd` following the `dt` shouldn't the XPaths look the same except for `dt` changing to `dd`?

Comment: Demo = (driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//div[@class='row p-3']/div/div/div/dl/dt[1]"))).getText());
   
System.out.println(Demo);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Kogan_Name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("\"//div[@class='row p-3']/div/div/div/dl/dd[1]")).getText();
System.out.println(Kogan_Name);     I replaced the dt with dd and upon validating the xpath on console it seems to work fine but when i am using the same xpath in script it says invalid selector error

Comment: I replaced the dt with dd but still it did not capture the text. I Also tried .getattribute("innerText") and  .getattribute("TextContent") but nothing is working out

Comment: Looking at `implicitWait` call before the `getText()` - I guess you expect the data to be present after some time. ImplicitWait waits only for the element to be present. Can you change it to a `sleep()` and check whether `getText()` returns proper value?

Comment: No it did not work with sleep and get text

Comment: Did you observe that you have an extra " in the XPath you posted in the comment?

Comment: Yes that is incorrect. I corrected that one and tried again but still it is not capturing

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using CSS instead of XPath? Also, your XPath expression seems too long. You may need to shorten it. I would try something like `//div[@class='row p-3']`. CSS expression for the same is `div[class='row p-3']`.

Comment: it is working with that xpath the issue is it is not capturing the text inside the dd tag

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got your answer already.

If you didn't, then a few possibilities would be -

```
koganName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//div[@class='row p-3']/div/div/div/dl/dt[1]/following-sibling::dd[1]"))).getText();

koganName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//div[@class='row mb-1']//dd[1]")).getText();

koganName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//div[@class='row mb-1']//dt[text() = 'Name:']/following-sibling::dd[1]")).getText();
```

Although, in each case, the **XPath** is still long and you can optimize it most definitely.

Also, like @Dakshinamurthy Karra mentioned, it would be more helpful if you posted the code snippet instead of screen captures.

Good luck and happy testing!

Comment: Hi Stephen, I tried your suggestions but nothing seems to work out :( Also tried .getattribute("innerText") and .getattribute("TextContent") with the xpath but still  nothing is going inside the Kogan_Name variable

Comment: Did you try it out like this:
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(""//div[@class='row p-3']//dl[@class='row mb-1']/dd[1]"));
String name = element.getAttribute("innerText");

What happens when you give the absolute xpath:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/app-root/app-track/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/dl/dd[1]")).getText();

Comment: none is working Stephen.

Comment: Hmm.. do you have firefox with firepath installed? Perhaps you can capture the xpath it provides and try checking if it works as is in your code? Without the DOM to work with, I am taking shots in the dark myself. Also, the implictlyWait will only wait for the element to be available and not the property/value itself. So yes, adding a thread.sleep() might also mitigate the issue.

Comment: Tried thread.sleep() as well. Let me try to install firepath and check the xpath once

Comment: I tried still the xpath generated is not capturing the text

Comment: The perhaps, use the javascriptexecutor directly - 
String name = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerText;",driver.findElement(By.xpath(""//div[@class='row p-3']/div/div/div/dl/dd[1]"")));
System.out.println(name);
That might help!

Comment: Also, While we are this far, can you try --> driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//div[@class='row p-3']/div/div/div/dl/child::dd[1]"))).getText();

Comment: On using  JavascriptExecutor i am getting null in the console when I am printing name

Comment: And Last one using Child is also not fetching the text

Answer (score 1):

This below code will surely help you.

**Try this**

```
public void click(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("ng-star-inserted"));
            List<WebElement> allrows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
          //  List<WebElement> allcols = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            for(WebElement row: allrows) {
                List<WebElement> Cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
                for(WebElement Cell:Cells) {
                    if (Cell.getText().contains("COASTAL"))
                        Cell.click();
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Welcome");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("call-caseDetail"))).click();
            System.out.println("first row is clicked");
            createDirector(wait, driver);
            updateDirector(wait, driver);
            deleteDirector(driver);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Timeout " + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit horizontal, but you might consider looking at using Protractor (wrapper of Selenium) to test this web app that looks like it must be Angular, before you get too far.  The value(s) you seek to extract might be more easily available via a Protractor specific locator (like ngmodel).

Comment: Hello.. Yes it is an angular application.. But I am already using Cucumber - Selenium framework is it possible to use Protector with Cucumber?

Comment: Perhaps with CucumberJS